# Hooking every function call in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hook, metaprogramming

I have a large codebase, which consists of thousands of functions.

I want to enable code execution before and after every function call, when the functions starts and when it ends.

Is there a way to do it without recompiling Python, or adding code to each function? Is there a way to hook every function call in my code?

Comment: You can create a decorator and execute some code before calling actual function....

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I don't want to add decorators to each function. I have several thousands of them. Also, I want to be able to run the code on another codebases.

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/profile.py

Comment: Yup, got to setprofile while searching for an answer. The problem is that `setprofile` doesn't catch the return value. Martin's answer is perfect. Thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can use either the [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) or [`sys.setprofile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile) functions to register a callback and handle `'call'` and perhaps `'return'` events. However, *this can slow down your code considerably*. Calling a function has overhead, adding another function call for every function call adds more overhead.

By default, the `sys.settrace()` hook is only called for calls (where *call* indicates a new scope being entered, including class bodies and list, dict and set comprehensions, as well as generator expressions), but you can optionally return a trace function to be called for the scope just entered. If you are only interested in calls then just return `None` from the trace function. Note that this lets you be selective about what scopes you gather more information about. `sys.settrace()` only reports on Python code, not built-in callables or those defined in compiled extensions.

The `sys.setprofile()` hook is called for calls to both Python functions and builtins and compiled  extension objects, and the same callback is also called whenever a call returns or an exception was raised. Unfortunately it’s not possible to distinguish between a Python function returning `None` or raising an exception.

In both cases you are given the current [frame](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects), as well as the event name and `arg`, usually set to `None` but for some events to something more specific:

```
def call_tracer(frame, event, arg):
    # called for every new scope, event = 'call', arg = None
    # frame is a frame object, not a function!
    print(f"Entering: {frame.f_code.co_name}")
    return None

sys.settrace(call_tracer)
```

When using `sys.settrace()` returning a function object instead of `None` lets you trace other events within the frame, this is the 'local' trace function. You can re-use the same function object for this. This slows things down more, because now you are calling a function for every line of source code. The local trace function is then called for `'line'`, `'exception'` and `'return'` events, but you can disable per-line events by setting `frame.f_trace_lines = False` (requires Python 3.7 or newer).

Here is a short demo of both hooks (assuming Python 3.7 or newer is used); it ignores the exception event option:

```
import sys

# demo functions, making calls and returning things

def foo(bar, baz):
    return bar(baz)

def spam(name):
    print(f"Hello, {name}")
    return [42 * i for i in range(17)]

# trace functions, one only call events, another combining calls and returns

def call_tracer(frame, event, arg):
    # called for every new scope, event = 'call', arg = None
    # frame is a frame object, not a function!
    print(f"Entering: {frame.f_code.co_name}")
    return None

def call_and_return_tracer(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'call':
        print(f"Entering: {frame.f_code.co_name}")
        # for this new frame, only trace exceptions and returns
        frame.f_trace_lines = False
        return call_and_return_tracer
    elif event == 'c_call':
        print(f"Entering: {arg.__name__}")
    elif event == 'return':
        print(f"Returning: {arg!r}")
    elif event == 'c_return':
        print(f"Returning from: {arg.__name__}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.settrace(call_tracer)
    foo(spam, "world")
    print()

    sys.settrace(call_and_return_tracer)
    foo(spam, "universe")
    print()
    sys.settrace(None)

    sys.setprofile(call_and_return_tracer)
    foo(spam, "profile")
```

Running this outputs:

```
Entering: foo
Entering: spam
Hello, world
Entering: <listcomp>

Entering: foo
Entering: spam
Hello, universe
Entering: <listcomp>
Returning: [0, 42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336, 378, 420, 462, 504, 546, 588, 630, 672]
Returning: [0, 42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336, 378, 420, 462, 504, 546, 588, 630, 672]
Returning: [0, 42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336, 378, 420, 462, 504, 546, 588, 630, 672]

Entering: foo
Entering: spam
Entering: print
Hello, profile
Returning from: print
Entering: <listcomp>
Returning: [0, 42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336, 378, 420, 462, 504, 546, 588, 630, 672]
Returning: [0, 42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336, 378, 420, 462, 504, 546, 588, 630, 672]
Returning: [0, 42, 84, 126, 168, 210, 252, 294, 336, 378, 420, 462, 504, 546, 588, 630, 672]
Returning: None
```

If possible to alter the code, add decorators only to the functions you want to trace, so you can limit the overhead. You can even automate this if you are prepared to write some code to do the alterations; with the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) you can parse code into object trees that can be transformed, including adding in `@decorator` syntax. This isn't *that* simple but really worth it if your codebase is large. See the [Green Tree Snakes project](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more in-depth documentation on how to do that.

Comment: Does this work in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @Hossein you’d have to call sys.set trace for each thread; see the function docs linked from my answer.

Comment: That's real cool. Can you do it more: print out the class name if it is a member of it , an the filename of the function and the line number of the function.

Comment: @AndyYuan: sure, see the documentation for the [frame object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects), and at [code objects](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-55) for the `frame.f_code` code object attributes. `frame.f_code.co_qualname` gives you the [*qualified name*](https://peps.python.org/pep-3155/), which includes the class for methods (so `ClassName.methodname` instead of just `methodname`),`frame.f_code.co_filename` gives you filename and `frame.f_lineno` the line number.